# Pandas set dtype when using loc to create a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a big fan of using `pd.DataFrame.loc` to create new columns given the value of existing columns e.g.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(1,10,1000).astype('u1'),'B':np.random.randint(1,100,1000).astype('u1')})
df.loc[df['A'] < 5, 'C'] = 40
print('df.head()\n', df.head(),'\n\ndf.dtypes\n', df.dtypes, sep='')

df.head()
   A   B    C
0  3  62  4.0
1  6  12  NaN
2  7  96  NaN
3  5  18  NaN
4  3  71  4.0

df.dtypes
A      uint8
B      uint8
C    float64
dtype: object
```

This does, however, return the column as float64 which is a significant upcast as well as the "wrong" dtype. I know you can cast the type after the fact i.e.

```
df['C'] = df['C'].astype('Int8')
print('df.head()\n', df.head(),'\n\ndf.dtypes\n', df.dtypes, sep='')

df['C'] = df['C'].astype('Int8')...
df.head()
   A   B    C
0  3  62    4
1  6  12  NaN
2  7  96  NaN
3  5  18  NaN
4  3  71    4

df.dtypes
A    uint8
B    uint8
C     Int8
dtype: object
```

Rather, I would like to be able to choose the dtype when creating the column, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The column has `float64` dtype because of `NaN` values:

```py
type(np.nan)
# float

pd.Series([40, np.nan])
# 0    40.0
# 1     NaN
# dtype: float64

pd.Series([40, 1])
# 0    40
# 1     1
# dtype: int64
```

---

Thus, the only fix I see is to make sure there won't be `NaN` values after conditional assignment (otherwise I'd just convert column to Int8 just like you did):

```py
df["C"] = np.where(
    df["A"] < 5, 40, 999
)

df.head()
#   A   B   C
#   9   40  999
#   2   76  40
#   4   82  40
```

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of the pandas "gotcha" that by default `NaN` will be cast to float. A recent experimental datatype, the nullable integer (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) seems like an attractive dtype for the scenario. I was wondering whether I could be more memory efficient when using loc and set the type before actually taking up memory. I like the np.where solution, however, I would prefer a NaN representation rather than an "if-else" scenario :/

Answer (score 0):

Using the `numpy.where()` as proposed by '*political-scientist*', the most efficient and fastest way that I've found is to set the 'else-statement' as `nan` and convert to dtype in one step

```
df["C"] = np.where(df["A"] < 5, 40, np.nan).astype('Int8')
```